# endpoints proto datastore: query structured property

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints, app-engine-ndb, endpoints-proto-datastore

I am trying to implement a search **based on the street** of an entity. like this;

tried:

```
class Address(EndpointsModel):
    street = ndb.StringProperty()

class Node(EndpointsModel):
    address = ndb.StructuredProperty(Address)

@Node.query_method(
    path='whatever',
    name='WhatEver',
    query_fields=('address',)
)
def nodes_by_street(self , query):
    return query
```

getting:

```
TypeError: Tried to use a ProtoRPC message field: MessageField. Only simple fields can be used when allow message fields is turned off.
```

I have tried adding `allow_message_fields` to `query_method`, it doesn't work.

I have tried changing `address` to `address.street` it doesn't work.

**Any ideas as to what should I do to make it work ?**

Comment: I suggest you use an EndpointsAliasProperty